# Microsoft Document Explorer displays warning after installing Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

After installing Visual Studio 2017, some pages in Microsoft Document Explorer now display a warning message: "This webpage might not be displayed properly. The content of the webpage does not match the type specified by the server. Click here for options..."

[image]

I hae encountered this problem before and the solution was to apply an update to Visual Studio 12. I never figured out the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by editing the registry. Edit the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and change the DWORD value to decimal 9000 for IE9 rendering mode depending on !DOCTYPE settings.

I already had this registry hack to get Microsoft Document Explorer out of its perpetual Internet Explorer 7 mode. Apparently installing Visual Studio 2017 changed this registry key.